# Python: Removing the numbers from a numbered list and removing items with certain characters

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains a numbered list of medications and chemical structures.

Is there a way I can remove the numbers in the front of the substance names?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
new_file = open("string_cleaned.txt", "w")
      
for line in open("string.txt", "r"):
  x = txt.lsplit(", ", 1)[1]
  new_file.write(x)


new_file.close()
```

Goal

```
From:
1 Substance 1
2 Substance 2

To:
Substance 1
Substance 2
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it's worth adding your desired output to your question. Do you have any code written so far? Have you at least read the file in and can iterate over the lines of text? If so, add that code.

Comment: If the motivation for removing certain formula names be that they are non IUPAC compliant, then a better approach would be to seek out a general regex or library which can validate IUPAC formula names.

Comment: @jarmod I just added the code I have so far.

Comment: What is the output that you need ? Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bulletproof solution but it may work if your data is like your example.
If it needs more tweaks tell me.

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase

YourFile = open("yourFile.txt", "r")
listOfLines = YourFile.readlines()


for lineIndex in range(len(listOfLines)):
    for char in listOfLines[lineIndex]:
        if char in alphabet:
            editedLine = listOfLines[lineIndex].split(char,1)[1]
            editedLine = str(lineIndex + 1) + "  " + char + editedLine  #(optional) If you need the Index numbers beside your items
            listOfLines[lineIndex] = editedLine
            break

anotherFile = open("anotherFile.txt", "w")
anotherFile.writelines(listOfLines)
anotherFile.close
```

So after the edit here is the solution

```
YourFile = open("yourFile.txt", "r")
listOfLines = YourFile.readlines()

for index in range(len(listOfLines)):
    listOfLines[index] = listOfLines[index].lstrip("0123456789")
    listOfLines[index] = listOfLines[index].lstrip(" ")

    print(listOfLines[index])


anotherFile = open("anotherFile.txt", "w")
anotherFile.writelines(listOfLines)
anotherFile.close
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** A specific solution.

```py
import re

result = ""
for line in open("string.txt"):
    result += re.sub(r"(?<=\s)[^a-zA-Z]*", "", line)

with open("string_cleaned.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(result)
```